# OnClickListener not working on views added programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

Ok, i have a method called "AddView()" When i long click, a rectangle shows up at my finger position, that works fine.

The problem is with the "selectView()" method. I've tried using both OnTouchListener  and OnLongClickListener, but nothing happens...

I just want a simple Toast to pop up when i long press a view that i've created with the "AddView"

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {

View _view;
ViewGroup _root;
private int _yDelta;
private int positionY;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    _root = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.root);
    _view = new View(this);

    addView();
    selectView();
}

private void selectView() {

    _view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Worked?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    _view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Worked?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}

private void addView() {

    _root.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            positionY = (int)event.getY();
            return false;
        }
    });

    _root.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            _view = new View(MainActivity.this);
            _view.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
            _view.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(1080, 100));
            _view.setTranslationX(0);
            _view.setTranslationY(positionY - 80);
            _view.setOnTouchListener(MainActivity.this);
            _view.setLongClickable(true);
            _root.addView(_view);

            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you assigning a new `View` in the `onCreate` without adding it to a parent `ViewGroup`?

Comment: I think you should use `findViewById(android.R.id.content);` to get an Activity's root view

Comment: @manfcas i had a problem with an OnTouchListner (that I did not show here) that keept saying that "_view" was a null object, and that seemed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are never setting the long click listener when you add the view.

Try like so

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    _root = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.root);

    _root.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            positionY = (int)event.getY();
            return false;
        }
    });

    addViewOnTouch(_root);
}

private void setTouchListener(final View touched) {

    touched.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Worked?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    touched.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Worked?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}

private void addViewOnTouch(final View touched) {

    touched.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            View _view = new View(MainActivity.this);
            _view.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
            _view.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(1080, 100));
            _view.setTranslationX(0);
            _view.setTranslationY(positionY - 80);
            _view.setOnTouchListener(MainActivity.this);
            _view.setLongClickable(true);

            setTouchListener(_view); // Need to set touch on new View

            touched.addView(_view);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @Axonshi123 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.